# Format String currency

Tags: java

I am trying to display 3000 as €300,0 using the code below :

```
String formattedString = String.format("%.2€;",3000);  
System.out.println("format: "+formattedString);
```

but result in force close error.

what am I missing?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberintro.html

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a locale-specific currency format instead

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
```

Better I18N that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Java API: NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html). It will show how to use **predefined** formats top achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);//use Locale.getDefault() if you didn't know the type
System.out.println(fmt.format(100.00));
```

This will print: £100.00